# Any way to index-match across rows and columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm struggling with conversion from one table format to another. Namely, my source data looks like this:

|  |  | Month | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Year | Country | Category | Export | Import | Export | Import |
| 2008 | France | 1 | 19298 | 25638 | 21354 | 19626 |
| 2008 | France | 2 | 2675 | 5359 | 3018 | 24423 |
| 2009 | France | 1 | 246781 | 175638 | 203479 | 174495 |
| 2009 | France | 2 | 96857 | 47429 | 104788 | 247950 |
| 2008 | Italy | 1 | 230999 | 133560 | 248414 | 147667 |
| 2008 | Italy | 2 | 235473 | 197860 | 258523 | 224402 |
| 2009 | Italy | 1 | 38453 | 5299 | 45022 | 6383 |
| 2009 | Italy | 2 | 88823 | 41088 | 93526 | 43115 |

but that's not usable.

I want to transform the table to look like this:

| Year | Month | Partner | Category | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2008 | 1 | France | 1 | Export | 19298 |
| 2008 | 1 | France | 1 | Import | 25638 |
| 2008 | 1 | France | 2 | Export | 2675 |
| 2008 | 1 | France | 2 | Import | 5359 |
| 2008 | 1 | Italy | 1 | Export | 230999 |
| 2008 | 1 | Italy | 1 | Import | 133560 |
| 2008 | 1 | Italy | 2 | Export | 235473 |
| 2008 | 1 | Italy | 2 | Import | 197860 |
| 2008 | 2 | France | 1 | Export | 21354 |
| 2008 | 2 | France | 1 | Import | 19626 |
| 2008 | 2 | France | 2 | Export | 3018 |
| 2008 | 2 | France | 2 | Import | 24423 |
| 2008 | 2 | Italy | 1 | Export | 248414 |
| 2008 | 2 | Italy | 1 | Import | 147667 |
| 2008 | 2 | Italy | 2 | Export | 258523 |
| 2008 | 2 | Italy | 2 | Import | 224402 |

but I don't know how to make the transformation.

I have tried to index-match but with two conditions I can't process all the values and with multiple conditions scanning rows and columns didn't work.

I have tried SUMIFS, but it requires identical ranges of criteria and summation.

Comment: Have you tried looking into `Power Query` if you are trying to transform the data? Also where does the last two columns go when you transformed it, because it should be there while you have not shown

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Export and Import are repeated in the source, I don't want it. How can I do it in Power Query?

Comment: You haven't got me, in the source you have let say for example the first row: `2008 France 1 19298 25638 21354 19626` which is showing the result table for 19298 and 25638 but not showing for 21354 and 19626

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I see, my bad. The different exports are supposed to refer to different months. I will try to fix it.

Comment: The 2nd month isn't in my desired table example, that's what caused confusion.

Comment: So you don't need the data for the year `2009`?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I do. I want to reorganize the entire dataset, that's all.

Comment: See I have posted in answers, also added a workbook, you can download to see. There is ofcourse one adjustment since `Structured references` cant hold duplicate headers, I have added those `1`s and `2`s in the second row with respective import and export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task can be accomplished quite easily using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> as well, which will be the **`easiest approach`**. Available in <kbd>Windows</kbd> **`Excel 2010+`** and **`Excel 365`** <kbd>Windows or Mac</kbd>

[image]

---

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table17"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Year", "Country", "Category"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("_", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Year", "Attribute.1", "Country", "Category", "Attribute.2", "Value"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Attribute.1", "Month"}, {"Attribute.2", "Type"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

**Workbook : [Download from here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cjkZ_1v_WM2GY8gvX?e=NV55Cj)**

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it in the morning. I've got Excel 2016.

Comment: @MehMech it will work, there wont be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use the VBA macro for this operation.
[image]

```
Sub Transform()
  Dim cr As Range, cc As Range, i As Integer
  With Sheet2
    Range([a2], [c2]).Copy .Cells(1, 1)
    Cells(1, 3).Copy .Cells(1, 4)
    .Cells(1, 5) = "Operation"
    .Cells(1, 6) = "Quantity"
    i = 2
    For Each cr In Range([a3], [a3].End(xlDown))
      For Each cc In Range([d1], [d1].End(xlToRight))
        Range(cr, cr.Offset(0, 2)).Copy .Cells(i, 1)
        Range(cc, cc.Offset(1, 0)).Copy
        .Cells(i, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone _
          , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        Cells(cr.Row, cc.Column).Copy .Cells(i, 6)
        i = i + 1
      Next
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

You don't need to modify it to adjust for numbers of columns and rows.

Run the macro while Sheet1 is active. The result is on Sheet2.

**Unpivot user-defined function**

Another way is to create and use a user-defined function:

```
Unpivot(HoleTable, TopLeftDataCell[, ColumnHeader1, ColumnHeader2, ...])
```

where

- HoleTable - the input table including row and column header (red framed on the picture below)
- TopLeftDataCell - the topmost leftmost cell of data range (green framed on the picture below)
- ColumnHeader1, ColumnHeader2, ... - names for column headers, can be any combination of ranges or values

[image]

```
Function Unpivot(table As Range, topleftvalue As Range, ParamArray headers() As Variant) As Variant
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long, titles As Variant
  Dim rh As Long, ch As Long, output() As Variant
  If table.Columns.Count < 3 Or table.Rows.Count < 3 Then
    Unpivot = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Exit Function
  End If
  rh = topleftvalue.Column - table.Column
  ch = topleftvalue.Row - table.Row
  If rh < 1 Or rh >= table.Columns.Count Or ch < 1 Or ch >= table.Rows.Count Then
    Unpivot = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Exit Function
  End If
  titles = headers
  titles = GetArray(ch, titles)
  ReDim output((table.Columns.Count - rh) * (table.Rows.Count - ch), rh + ch) As Variant
  For i = 1 To rh
    output(0, i - 1) = table.Cells(ch, i)
  Next
  For i = 0 To ch
    output(0, rh + i) = titles(i)
  Next
  m = 1
  For i = ch + 1 To table.Rows.Count
    For j = rh + 1 To table.Columns.Count
      For k = 1 To rh
        output(m, k - 1) = table.Cells(i, k)
      Next
      For k = 1 To ch
        output(m, rh + k - 1) = table.Cells(k, j)
      Next
      output(m, rh + ch) = table.Cells(i, j)
      m = m + 1
    Next
  Next
  Unpivot = output
End Function

Function GetArray(dn As Long, sa As Variant) As Variant
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, p As Long, m As Long, n As Long, o As Long, r As Long
  Dim v As Variant, va As Variant, ia As Boolean
  ReDim oa(dn) As String
  If (IsEmpty(sa)) Then
    i = -1
  Else
    i = UBound(sa)
  End If
  r = i
  p = 0
  m = 0
  For j = 0 To dn
    ia = True
    While ia
      If p > i Then
        ia = False
      Else
        If IsArray(sa(p)) Then
          If IsEmpty(sa(p)) Then
            p = p + 1
          Else
            If m = 0 Then
              va = sa(p)
              m = UBound(va, 1)
              n = UBound(va, 2)
              r = r + m * n - 1
              k = 1
              o = 1
            End If
            If k <= m And o <= n Then
              v = va(k, o)
              o = o + 1
              If o > n Then
                o = 1
                k = k + 1
              End If
              ia = False
            Else
              m = 0
              p = p + 1
            End If
          End If
        Else
          v = sa(p)
          p = p + 1
          ia = False
        End If
      End If
    Wend
    oa(j) = IIf(j <= r, v, IIf(j = dn, "Value", "Colum" & (j + 1)))
  Next
  GetArray = oa
End Function
```

'GetArray(N as long, InputArray as variant)' is the supporting function which returns an array of N column names taking them from InputArray as well as values are available in it. If no/not all values provided, the function returns { "Column1", "Column2", ... "Value" } or the tail of this array.